# Jquery if value is greater than a certain length

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write some validation to check and see if a field is greater than a certain length and if it is throw an error. I can't seem to get it to work though and when I search for something normally take the .val() route to validate.

So I have

```
 $('.btn-danger').on('click', function(){
   if ($('input[name="spine_text"]').length > 22) {
     $('.spineError').html('This field must only have 22 characters.');
     $('.spineError').addClass('marginBottom');
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: ($('.cloth').first().offset().top)
     },500);
     $('.clothError').html('');
     return false;
   }

  });
```

and I have tried `.length() > 22` as well. Neither of them work.

A jsFiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/PE6rD/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the length of value of the input field, use `.val()` to get the value.

```
if ($('input[name="spine_text"]').val().length > 22) {
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n57Gt/)

when you say `$('input[name="spine_text"]').length` it returns the number of input elements with name `spine_text`

Comment: That makes cense! Thank you so much, I knew I was forgetting something silly!